# Class implementation involving CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I'm having some problem with implementation the class Location.
When I start the application I call class Location in StartApp.m, I want to print to test the variable cidade but  the  result to Cidade2 and Cidade3 is null in NSLog, I'm doing something too wrong? I tryed change the code, but I can't resolve the problem. Other thing that I don't understand is why the NSLog Cidade2 is printing nil, the variable is the Location class too. 
Tks for help!

**Output :**

```
2013-02-20 21:58:09.648 MPA[484:11603] Cidade 2: (null)
2013-02-20 21:58:09.650 MPA[484:11603] Cidade 3 : (null)
2013-02-20 21:58:09.661 MPA[484:11603] Resolving the Address
2013-02-20 21:58:10.390 MPA[484:11603] Found placemarks: (
    "Apple Store, San Francisco, Apple Store, San Francisco, 1800 Ellis St, San Francisco, CA  94115-4004, United States @ <+37.78584540,-122.40651750> +/- 100.00m, region (identifier <+37.78584545,-122.40652160> radius 18.96) <+37.78584545,-122.40652160> radius 18.96m"
), error: (null)
2013-02-20 21:58:10.391 MPA[484:11603] Cidade : California
```

**Localizacao.m**

```
#import "Localizacao.h"

@interface Localizacao ()

@end

@implementation Localizacao


@synthesize cidade,estado,latSend,lonSend;

-(void)startLocalizacao
{

    lm = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    lm.delegate = self;
    lm.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    lm.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc]init];

    NSLog(@"Cidade 2: %@", cidade);


}

//Adicionado para pegar a localizacao atual

-(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    //Display Latitude
    latSend = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;


    //Display Longitude

    lonSend = newLocation.coordinate.longitude ;


    //Display Accurancy

    NSString *acc = [[ NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:@"%f",
                     newLocation.horizontalAccuracy];

    //Update MAP
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = .001;
    span.longitudeDelta= .001;


    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = newLocation.coordinate;
    region.span = span;



    [acc release];


    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];



            /*NSString *teste = [[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
             placemark.subThoroughfare,
             placemark.thoroughfare,
             placemark.postalCode,
             placemark.locality,
             placemark.administrativeArea,
             placemark.country];*/

            cidade = placemark.administrativeArea;
            estado = placemark.locality;

            [lm stopUpdatingLocation];

            NSLog(@"Cidade : %@", cidade);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];


}

@end
```

**StartApp.m**

```
#import "StartApp.h"
#import "Localizacao.h"

@interface StartApp ()

@end

@implementation StartApp

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Localizacao *localizacao = [[Localizacao alloc] init];

    [localizacao startLocalizacao];

    NSLog(@"Cidade3 : %@", localizacao.cidade);


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Tks for help me

Answer (score 2):

You create your `Localizacao` instance and then call `startLocalizacao`. The `startLocalizacao` method sets up the location manager and asks it to start. It then logs `Cidade 2`. This log happens before the location manager has finished initializing and before the first location is received by the app. All of this initialization is done in the background by the location manager.

You are not doing anything wrong (other than adding log statements for data that is not yet initialized). You just have to realize that the location events are asynchronous and they come it when they are available.

Comment: Tks rmaddy to update. I don't have many skills with asynchronous and threads . How can I wait the location manager finish to give a value in localizacao.cidade ? I was searching for dispatch_async is it correct ?

Tks

Comment: Friends, can you help me about this question ? I can't run my code yet.Tks